# Can you power on a MacBook with a wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, wifi, macbook-pro, power

Is it possible to power on a MacBook using a wireless keyboard?
If that sounds strange, I'm asking because I use a Bose radio as the sound system and the radio fits nicely on top of the laptop.

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot power on a laptop (or desktop, for that matter) from a wireless keyboard (or a wired USB keyboard).

You *can*, however, wake the computer from sleep with a wireless keyboard.